# How to write regular expressions for json object?

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regex and already asked to write some complicated expression (well, they may be simple but for me they are not :) ).
I have tried many variations and never succeed. The expressions I'm trying to write are:
1. {"d":{"results":SOME_JSON_OBJECT}}
2. {"d":{"results":{"JSON_KEY_AS_STRING":SOME_JSON_ARRAY/OBJECT}}}
3. {"d":{"results":[SOME_JSON_OBJECTS]}}
4. {"d":SOME_JSON_ARRAY/OBJECT_OR_AN_PRIMITIVE}
Notice, that ANY_VALUE can be anything. The only thing that matter is all characters that are not ANY_VALUE, including all "special" characters such as ", {, } , [, ], :, etc...

Can anyone assist? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use a JSON parser?

Comment: I'm holding this as Strings. I can parse them with JSON parser and than manually check, but I would like to identify the pattern in advance if possible.

Comment: If you want a parser, write a parser.

Comment: Something like "if(obj.get("d").equals("result")" -> if(obj.get("result").isJsonArray() .... stuff like that.

Comment: Why would you want to do that with anything other than a json parser? You have to get the structure no matter what-why not use something that already does?

Comment: You are correct Dave. Please consider my discussion below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java regex flavour doesn't support recursive patterns in the regex (PCRE and .NET have extensions allowing for recursive patterns).

Therefore, you cannot have a regex parse the objects properly, since they can have an arbitrary depth. What you need is a JSON parser, and if you want to write that yourself I suggest that you have a look at parser tools such as ANTLR or GOLD, which assist you in the process (you write a grammar for the parsing, and then the tool creates the actual parsing code for you).

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/bsn-goldparser/wiki/JsonGrammar)'s a JSON grammar I wrote some time ago for GOLD.

Comment: I see. But your patterns do not make much sense: if `ANY_VALUE` can be anything including `{` and `}` then this means that your patterns 1-3 are already a match of pattern 4, and the only thing you want to look for really is `\{\s*"d"\s*:` (as regex).

Comment: I get what your'e saying but please notice that there is a difference between 2 and 3 ({ vs. [) and in 2, the first ANY_VALUE actually is a json key which means it will be some String. I don't know if any of what I said matter, but I'm new to regex, so please understand if not :)

Comment: Oh no I really get what you have said about 4 that "contains" all first 3. So i guess i'll use the JSON parser. This is probably the best... :\

Comment: Can you clarify: is `ANY_VALUE` allowed to be a JSON object or array or only a simple value (e.g. string, number, boolean or null)? Because if it can only be a simple value, then your patterns 1 and 2 are not valid JSON. Otherwise, 4 contains all the others as I wrote.

Comment: OK i'll try t clarify: In 1, The key is 'result' and the value is ANY_VALUE will be some JSON object. In 2, the first ANY_VALUE is a String (because it will represent a JSON key) and the second is an object - as same as in 1 - or a JSON array. In 3, the ANY_VALUE will be some JSON objects (they will be inside an array). In 4 it can by either JSON array or JSON object or primitive. I'll try to edit my question...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. In that case my remark about pattern 4 matching 1-3 as well is correct. Do you need to know which pattern matched?

Comment: I think i give up and will use the JSON parser instead. I wanted to make my life easier (and avoid using external jars) but as you said - 4 matches 1-3 so regex won't help me in this case. Thank you very much for your willing to help anyways. I really appreciate it!